# wxWebView in wxHaskell

Tags: haskell, wxhaskell

I'm trying to show a web page inside my wxHaskell based application for Mac. I tried to use `HtmlWindow`, which is very limited. According to the wxWidgets' documentation, I have to use wxWebView, which is capable to process CSS and JS.

From http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_html_window.html

> If you want complete HTML/CSS support as well as a Javascript engine, see instead wxWebView.

Exactly what I need! Hoverer I didn't find any mentions of wxWebView in wxHaskell. And, also, which is miracle, Google is pretty silent about it. That makes me think, that I do something wrong. Is there any way to display reach (having HTML/CSS/JS) pages using wxHaskell? How do people do that?

I've got wxWidgets 3.0.2 installed from brew:

```
brew install wxwidgets
```

and wxHaskell 0.92 from cabal

```
cabal install wx
cabal install wxcore
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wxWebView is not implemented in wxHaskell (yet); feel free to create a pull request to expand wxHaskell.

B.t.w. if you ask questions at the [wxhaskell-users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/wxhaskell-users), you probably get an answer sooner.